# Wrong topology configuration issue

Tags: content-delivery, dxa, content-manager, web8, sdl-tridion

I have wrongly configured Topology manager and one website in content delivery . Both my CM and CD are on same physical machine but while configuring presentation server website ,I have provided same port number 82 for my website as well(topology manager is still running on port 82). Is it possible to update or remove this website configuration from topology database and insert again?

Answer (score 8):

To update Website in Topology Manager use following command:

```
Set-TtmWebsite -Id websiteId -BaseUrls newBaseUrls
```

Full list of Topology Manager commands are listed by: [docs](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3BD6ED93-41B7-4357-92DB-8AEA8DEFB0A1)

Comment: You can also make use of standard PowerShell features to learn about the cmdlets that are available. I have written a blog on this (http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/finding-your-way-around-the-sdl-web-8-cmdlets).

Comment: Wow!! ..thanks :)